# ember-cli test not working with phantomjs in docker

Tags: ember.js, phantomjs, ember-cli, testem

When running `ember test --host 172.17.0.2 --test-port 4450`, I'm getting the following error.

`Error: Browser failed to connect within 30s. testem.js not loaded?`

Since I'm using a docker container I'm assuming I need to update the host and port to the open docker host and port.

This is my `testem.js` file

```
/*jshint node:true*/
module.exports = {
  "framework": "qunit",
  "test_page": "tests/index.html?hidepassed",
  "phantomjs_debug_port": 4500,
  "disable_watching": true,
  "launch_in_ci": [
    "PhantomJS"
  ],
  "launch_in_dev": [
    "PhantomJS",
    "Chrome"
  ]
};
```

Comment: Have you managed to solve the issue?

Comment: Note that Ember has dropped support for PhantomJS in favor of headless Chrome. See https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/pull/15877

Answer (score 1):

This is a general problem you'll see when testing an ember application in continuous integration environments. Multiple users have posted their experiences with the possible bug in this [GitHub issue](https://github.com/testem/testem/issues/1021). 2 answers come to mind.

1. Per Testem's author, you can increase the browser [connection timeout](https://github.com/testem/testem/issues/1021#issuecomment-261784931).
2. Compare your ember application's `.travis.yml` with the canonical version in the ember-new-output repository [here](https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-new-output/blob/master/.travis.yml). The ember-cli core team and community members have invested a lot of time refining and debugging that `.travis.yml` to make it work well with ember applications.

Comment: This is an ongoing concern even today using Headless Chrome and Github Actions.  Setting the Testem option: `browser_start_timeout: 60` fixed it!